# node.js coffeescript - issues with requiring modules

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm having another issue with node.js, this time I cannot get my javascript code to recognize that a coffeescript module's class has functions.

In my main file, main.js I have the following code:

```
require('./node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script');
var Utils = require('./test');
console.log(typeof Utils);
console.log(Utils);
console.log(typeof Utils.myFunction);
```

And in my module, test.coffe, I have the following code:

```
class MyModule

  myFunction : () ->
    console.log("debugging hello world!")

module.exports = MyModule
```

Here is the output when I run `node main.js` :

```
function
[Function: MyModule]
undefined
```

My question is, why is my main file loading the correct module, but why is it unable to access the function? What am I doing wrong, whether it be with the coffeescript syntax, or with how I am requiring my module? Let me know if I should clarify my question.

Thanks,

Vineet

Comment: Try `require('coffee-script');` rather than using a full path.  Stuff in node_modules is automatically picked up automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`myFunction` is an *instance* method, so it won't be accessible directly from the `class`.

If you want it as a *class* (or *static*) method, prefix the name with `@` to refer to the class:

```
class MyModule

  @myFunction : () ->
    # ...
```

You can also export an `Object` if the intention is for all methods to be *static*:

```
module.exports =

  myFunction: () ->
    # ...
```

Otherwise, you'll need to create an instance, either in `main`:

```
var utils = new Utils();
console.log(typeof utils.myFunction);
```

Or, as the export object:

```
module.exports = new Utils
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply! This fixed it :] I can't accept it yet, but I will once the waiting period is over.